# A term that's more precise than "technical writing" that refers to the writing found in patent description

Tags: vocabulary

I am wondering if there's any such term. It's hard to think there's no such word, because the technical writing found in patent document is entirely different from those found in scientific research.

Comment: "Patent writing" is a term for the activity and the specialised skill, but I don't know if it's used like "technical writing" to also refer to the text that's produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also heard "patent writing."

It could be that patent writing is technical writing, but technical writing isn't necessarily patent writing.